# Registering a DCOM Server and running a client from remote system

Tags: delphi, com, delphi-2007, dcom

I built a sample application for dcom by following the steps given in [this link](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/23185).

After building the client and test DCom server, i tried to run client in my system and it worked correctly. But if i try to rum client from remote location, an error message is coming saying "Access is denied".

How can i run my client in remote location?

And also will i able to see the test DCOM Server in dcomcnfg.exe?

If yes where can i see it?

I was able to see it in regedit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might well have already done this, but can I just cover some basics...?

Go to the "Component Services" MMC snap-in, right-click on "My Computer" there and select "Properties".

In the "Default Properties" tab, make sure that "Enable Distributed COM on this computer" is enabled.

In the "COM Security" tab, make sure the access, launch and activate permissions are configured to allow the scenario you're in.

Answer (score 0):

The followings are what I have got so far, but I am still digging, you may find a better way anyway. Do the followings with elevated permission.

1. First run the server.exe on both computer to register them (/regserver).
2. Add incoming firewall rules on server machine to accept incoming client DCOM connection.
3. Define same user with same password on both computer (assuming you are not in a Domain). Add them to "Distributed COM Users".
4. run DCOMCNFG and do the followings:

   - Console Root>Component Services>Computers>My Computer>Properties>Default Properties>Enable Distributed COM on this computer
   - Console Root>Component Services>Computers>My Computer>Properties>Default Properties>Default Authentication Level>Connect
   - Console Root>Component Services>Computers>My Computer>Properties>Default Properties>Default Impersonation Level>Identify
   - Console Root>Component Services>Computers>My Computer>Properties>Default Protocols>Connection-oriented TCP/IP
   - Console Root>Component Services>Computers>My Computer>Properties>COM Security>Access Permissions>Edit Limits>Add "Distributed COM Users" with Local and Remote Access enabled
   - Console Root>Component Services>Computers>My Computer>Properties>COM Security>Lunch and Activation Permissions>Edit Limits>Add "Distributed COM Users" with Local and Remote Lunch and Activation enabled
   - Under My Computer find the server (it should be there if it is registered correctly)
   - server.exe>Properties>General>Authentication Level>Default
   - server.exe>Properties>Location>Run application on this computer enabled
   - server.exe>Security>Lunch and Activation Permissions>Customize>Edit>Add Distributed COM Users with Local and Remote Lunch and Activation enabled
   - server.exe>Security>Access Permissions>Customize>Edit>Add Distributed COM Users with Local and Remote Access enabled
   - server.exe>Endpoints>DCOM-Oriented endpoints>Add Connection-oriented TCP/IP
   - server.exe>Identity>select The interactive user or The launching user, which one is appropriate

After the above setting I am always able to call implemented server interface from the client application.

I hope it helps,
Zonouzi